# String variable in file handling not working

Tags: c, string, scanf

```
void addstd()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char name[50];
    char ID[5];
    int year;
    float gpa;
    printf("Input name of student\n");
    scanf("%s",name);
    printf("Enter ID\n");
    scanf("%s",ID);
    printf("Enter gpa\n");
    scanf("%f",&gpa);
    printf("Enter year of admission\n");
    scanf("%d",&year);
    printf("%s",name);
    fp=fopen("report.txt","a");
    fprintf(fp,"%s\t%s\t%0.1f\t%d",name,ID,gpa,year);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Probably a very silly error from my side, but the `name` variable is not printing any value in the terminal or in the file.

Comment: check weather you are calling this function or not

Comment: @user3121023 yes it's working but now the input for gpa is getting skipped

Comment: Change data type of gpa to double

Comment: @user3121023 for example AB300, following what you said the output only prints up till AB30, missing the last character

Comment: @VishwajeetBarve the same problem remains

Comment: `AB300` is 5 characters, your `ID` can only hold 4 characters, *excluding* the null terminator. Please don't forget about the null terminator